# Show/Hide create date in article not working properly

Tags: joomla-3.x, featured-articles

I want to hide the create date for a specific menu item with type **Featured Articles**. For this, I did the following:

1. **Menu item > Options > Create Date : show** . But it doesn't display in frontend.

   But when I select the following option along with the above option, it displays in frontend.
2. **Menu item > Options > Category: show** now it displays both the category and create date.

Can anyone please guide me on this. I only want to show the `create date` and NOT `category`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are options in the Backend

`Content -> article -> open article -> option(tab)`  for `Show Create Date`

Also in the `global configuration -> articles`

Comment: I checked every option. But it is set properly. Still not working

Comment: then it must be the `overrider `. Check `default template -> html -> com_content` directory

Comment: yes it was the overider :) thank you so much. There was some modifications done , I checked.

Comment: happy to help you :)